# Opening Documents SharePoint 2007 and Office 2013 Citrix VDI

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, document-library

We have encountered an issue where when end-users click a direct link to a document in SharePoint 2007 that is shared with them via email the document opens in protected mode and then when the user clicks `Edit Document` they see the message below.

> We're having trouble connecting to the server. If this keeps
>   happening, contact your help desk.

Our scenario is that we use Citrix VDI desktops with IE 9 32-bit and not all of the users are experiencing the same issue even though their desktop sessions are identical.

How do we begin to troubleshoot this?

Comment: The users having the issues, do they have permissions to Read/Edit the document?  Permissions to the doc library?

Comment: They have Contribute permissions.